# IIS SMTP some mails had been lost

Tags: iis-7, smtp

I am using SMTP server built in to the IIS. Over website sends email via this SMTP server and unfortunately we had lost some emails. I looked in to the SMTP log and I could not read that log properly since I could not find any useful tool that can read this log file. It's very hard to understand this log file. If someone give a useful tool that can read IIS SMTP server log, it would be a great help.

I have few other questions too.

The status for the lost email is 250 in the log file, does this mean everything went OK.

Is this SMTP server reliable enough to handle big number of emails at same time?

If not what would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to all of this would be to use a 3rd party mail server provider. Some good ones below:

http://www.aweber.com/ 
http://mailchimp.com/ 
http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp

They have API you can implement and use in your code to send e-mails through their SMTP.
If you're sending big number of emails at the same time, it is better to use these as your ISP may be blocking your outgoing e-mails since they're in big numbers. They do this to prevent spam and hacking.

Sorry that I couldn't help with the log but consider this information too.